# SemanticZoom Handling 3 levels

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, semantic-zoom

the problem is that i want to handle 3 lvl Zooms.

Lowest level - Articles
Between level - Mounths
Top level - Years

For this example i have used custom control and backgrounds.

Top level - is blue.
Between level - is red.
Lowest level GridView - is filled with 30 items of custom controls.

**Problem is that i some why cant scroll my lowest level GridView.**

Here is my xaml:

```
<SemanticZoom Grid.Row="1">
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                <GridView>
                    <SemanticZoom Grid.Row="1">
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                            <GridView x:Name="NewsListBox">
                                <GridView.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF006C67" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                </GridView.Background>
                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapGrid ItemHeight="200" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            </GridView>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                            <GridView Background="Red"/>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                    </SemanticZoom>
                </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                <GridView Background="Blue"/>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        </SemanticZoom>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Semantic Zoom control for Windows 8 was designed to provide only two levels.  This is based on user research which found that more than two levels confused users.  See the design guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn439345.aspx). I suggest that you use the Semantic zoom in combination with page navigation.